# How do I make bunch of objects be in one plane?

Tags: modeling

How do I take these blocks:
[image]

And place them all in one plane to get something like this:
[image]

So that none are sticking out or pushed in?
I run in similar situations all the time and I wonder if there is any way to do it more efficiently than manually rearanging each block, witch is next to impossible to level perfectly

Comment: maybe enable the Snap option (Face mode) to make them stick to a vertical plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- enable the `Objects: Align Tools` addon
  [image]
- select all objects to be aligned. the active object will be the reference object
  [image]
- go to n-panel > item > align tools and choose appropriate align location axis (here, y)
  [image]